# How to make this JS function work for each div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace last visible word with span of each div.

I used following code. **It works but only for first div** & it messes up all next div.
Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/samarpw/yfthoa5j/

```
var $div = $('div'),
    size = [$div.width(), $div.height()],
    words = $.trim($div.text()).split(/\s+/),
    word;

for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
    var $clone = $div.clone().text(words.join(' ')).insertAfter($div);
    $clone.contents().wrap('<span />');
    var $child = $clone.children('span');

    if ($child.width() <= size[0] && $child.height() <= size[1]) {
        word = words.pop();
        $clone.remove();
        break;
    }

    words.pop();
    $clone.remove();
}

$('.txt').html($('.txt').html().replace(word, "<span class='red'>"+word+"</span>"));
```

Comment: Your code gets the text of the first `div` and replaces all elements with class `txt` with it, it does what we could expect. You should use `var $div = $('div.txt')` tou limit yourself to the divs with the good class, then use `$div.each(function)` to do the code for each div. (Use `$(this)` inside the function to refer to the div)

Comment: @Kaddath can you help me giving some code hint (so that it work for each div text & don't mess up). I don't know much about javascript. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery Example might be helpful..

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.txt').each(function(index, el) {

  // Text Container Selector
  var $txt = $(this);

  // Selector Current Top Position
  var txtPos = $txt.offset().top;

  // Selector Height
  var size = $txt.innerHeight();

  // Get Words Array from String
  var txt_str = $txt.text().split(' ');

  // Make Emplty Selector's content
  $txt.html(' ');

  // Default Value of Last Word Index
  var last_word_index = 0;

  // Loop throught Each Word Araay Element
  $.each(txt_str, function(index, el) {

   // Wrap Each Word with <span> tag to Compare Top Position Selector
   $txt.append('<span>'+this+' </span>');

   // Currently appended <span> tag Index
   var $txtSpan = $txt.find('span').eq(index);

   // Currently appended <span> tag Top Position
   var txtSpanPos = $txtSpan.offset().top;

   // Currently appended <span> tag Height
   var txtSpansize = $txtSpan.innerHeight();

   // Comparing currently appended <span> tag position with Selector and Getting First not visible character
   if (txtSpanPos >= txtPos+size-(txtSpansize/1.5) && last_word_index <= 0) {

    // Getting previous <span> tag index of not visible Word 
    last_word_index = index - 1;
   }
  });

  // Declare new string variable
  var new_str = '';

  // Loop throught Each Word Araay Element
  $.each(txt_str, function(index, el) {

   var new_word = this;

   // New String Last word is wrapped with Span if all words are visible
   if (last_word_index == 0) {
    last_word_index = txt_str.length-1;
   }

   // Only last visible word is wrapped with Span
   if (index == last_word_index) {
    new_word = '<span class="red">'+new_word+'</span>';
   }
   new_str += new_word+' ';
  });

  // Adding all new string in Selector
  $txt.html(new_str);
 });
});
```

```css
.txt{
 width: 60px;
 height: 80px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.red {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</div>
<br>
<div class="txt">this is great to test if it is working.</div>
<br>
<div class="txt">Another example to test code working or not.</div>
```